# Regex to remove text in brackets if year present

Tags: regex, ruby, parsing

Remove all text within brackets if a year YYYY is present at any position within brackets.

Here is what I tried already:

```
a = []
while line = DATA.gets       
  a = a.push(line.split(/\(.+\d{4}.+\)/))
end                        

a.each {|x|
p x}
__END__
Start text (Name, 2019) and more text (reg bracket - keep) and more text (2018 references - remove).
```

I am expecting this text returned: "Start text and more text (reg bracket - keep) and more text."

Comment: I'd suggest `/\([^()]*\b\d{4}\b[^()]*\)/` to avoid matching `(00000000008)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is indeed a good suggestion.

Comment: Your expected result contradicts your statement of the problem. Presumably, you want to remove the parentheses as well as the string they contain, and also a space if two spaces would be left after removing `"(...)"`.

Comment: Well, `s.split(/\s*\([^()]*\b\d{4}\b[^()]*\)/).join("")` or `s.gsub(/\s*\([^()]*\b\d{4}\b[^()]*\)/, '').strip` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If the 4 digits can be at any position and there are no further opening and closing parenthesis, one option to get that match could be to:

Match the opening parenthesis, then match 0+ times not an opening or closing parenthesis. Then match 4 digits and again 0+ times not an opening or closing parenthesis.

```
\([^()]*\d{4}[^()]*\)
```

See a [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/vBo0WrqZ78803V)